# Call REST API https with certificate, key and CAcertificate

Tags: curl, https, openssl

I need to call a payment solution provider REST API endpoint with SSL authentication.

The provider gives me these files :

- merchantCA.crt
- rootCA.crt
- client.crt
- client.key
- client.pfx
- a passphrase

The API documentation says for the rootCA.crt that this is the certificate authority that signed the certificates provider servers use to authenticate when they connect to the merchant.

And merchantCA.crt is the certificate authority that signed the merchant certificate

So this is my CURL call :

`curl --cacert rootCA.crt --cert client.crt:passphrase --key client.key -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "https://provider_website/api/desired_endpoint"`

But I received this error

`curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:140AB18E:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ca md too weak, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)`

No idea what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem with an OpenVPN client, which is using OpenSSL (just like your curl is).
The problem could be that your OpenSSL client is too new. You need an older OpenSSL client.

Your newer OpenSSL client don't accept that the SSL server is using a md5 hashed certificate. It demands the server certificate is hashed using SHA256.

So by getting an older OpenSSL client, then it will accept the MD5 hashed certificate.

You can find old OpenVPN releases in https://build.openvpn.net/downloads/releases/
For Windows the newest one accepting MD5 is `openvpn-install-2.4.3-I602.exe`.
When you install that one it will install into `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin`. There you will find an `openssl.exe` that works. 
Here is the version it prints to me:

```
> openssl version
# OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
```

You can probably go directly to OpenSSL somwhere to fetch it if that is what you prefer.

OpenVPN also have versions for Linux and Mac. Perhaps that is also 2.4.3 version numbering for those platforms.

The other option is that your payment provider installs a certificate created by SHA256 (and supplies the new certificate to you, too). Apparently the MD5 certificates are not secure anymore...

Quote:

> OpenSSL version was upgraded to 1.1 and I cannot connect to my R7000
>   Router from Outside anymore, because for security reasons OpenSSL
>   v.1.1 doesn't accept MD5 certificates because have a weak signature.

From https://community.netgear.com/t5/Nighthawk-WiFi-Routers/Netgear-R7000-and-OpenVPN-for-Android-App/td-p/1310857

More on MD5 certificates: https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/faq-regarding-openvpn-connect-ios/#md5-signature-algorithm-support

This will tell you that you can check that the certificate is hashed using MD5: (use Git Bash)

```
 ../bin/openssl x509 -in rootCA.crt -noout -text | grep "Signature Algorithm"
#    Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
```